# Get Country ISO Codes from Website

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, powershell-5.0

I am trying to retrieve the ISO Codes for countries in either a CSV or a JSON format. My Code is as below:

```
# ############################
$logFile = "$env:USERPROFILE\desktop\ISOCountry.log"
Start-Transcript -Path $logFile -Append
#########################################

$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest "http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/diverse/doc/ISO_3166.html"
#$WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1"
$PRETAG = $WebResponse.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("PRE") | select -expand innertext
$PRETAG
$JsonText = $PRETAG | ConvertTo-csv
$JsonText
# end logging 
###########################
Stop-Transcript
###########################
```

The data is within the `PRE` tag and is all probably in tab delimited format. Need help on this. I am using the site as this is a free site.

I have tried retrieving data from the Wiki and unable to retrieve the same using the code below:

```
$URI = “https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1“
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI
($HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('table') | Where{ $_.className -eq 'wikitable sortable' }).innerText
```

Still facing the same problem. Need assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something i would do with the **HTMLAgilityPack**.
You can download the pack from http://html-agility-pack.net/
It is a well known and respected framework used for scraping websites in combination with XPath.

```
cls
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\temp\HtmlAgilityPack\lib\Net20\HtmlAgilityPack.dll”)
[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb]$web = @{}
[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument]$doc = $web.Load("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1")

## FILTER NEEDED CONTENT THROUGH X-PATH
[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection]$country = $doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[2]//tr//td[1]")
[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection]$iso = $doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[2]//tr//td[5]")

# go trough the arrays and put each item into output
$output = @()
for($i=0; $i -le $country.selectnodes.Count; $i++){

    $output += [pscustomobject] @{
    country = $country[$i].InnerText
    iso = $iso[$i].innertext
    }    
}
# export csv
$output | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation | out-file C:\temp\iso.csv  -Force
```

This would give you an output like:

```
"country";"iso"
"Afghanistan";"ISO 3166-2:AF"
"Aland Islands !Åland Islands";"ISO 3166-2:AX"
"Albania";"ISO 3166-2:AL"
"Algeria";"ISO 3166-2:DZ"
"American Samoa";"ISO 3166-2:AS"
```

EDIT: Found a more performant way

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the **HTMLAgility** module. I do not have **ADMIN** rights to install the module and so This is how I did it:

```
<################################################CODE HEADER############################################
SCRIPT NAME       : ISO Country Code.ps1
DESCRIPTION       : 
RUNTIME PARAMETERS: 
INPUT PARAMETERS  : 
OUTPUT PARAMETERS : 
Date                                                     Developer                                    Description 
--------------------------------------  ----------------------------------------------    --------------------------------- 

################################################CODE HEADER############################################>

<################################################SAMPLE DATA############################################
name           : Zimbabwe
topLevelDomain : {.zw}
alpha2Code     : ZW
alpha3Code     : ZWE
callingCodes   : {263}
capital        : Harare
altSpellings   : {ZW, Republic of Zimbabwe}
region         : Africa
subregion      : Eastern Africa
population     : 14240168
latlng         : {-20.0, 30.0}
demonym        : Zimbabwean
area           : 390757.0
gini           : 
timezones      : {UTC+02:00}
borders        : {BWA, MOZ, ZAF, ZMB}
nativeName     : Zimbabwe
numericCode    : 716
currencies     : {@{code=BWP; name=Botswana pula; symbol=P}, @{code=GBP; name=British pound; symbol=£}, @{code=CNY; name=Chinese yuan; symbol=¥}, @{code=EUR; name=Euro; 
                 symbol=€}...}
languages      : {@{iso639_1=en; iso639_2=eng; name=English; nativeName=English}, @{iso639_1=sn; iso639_2=sna; name=Shona; nativeName=chiShona}, @{iso639_1=nd; iso639_2=nde; 
                 name=Northern Ndebele; nativeName=isiNdebele}}
translations   : @{de=Simbabwe; es=Zimbabue; fr=Zimbabwe; ja=ジンバブエ; it=Zimbabwe; br=Zimbabwe; pt=Zimbabué; nl=Zimbabwe; hr=Zimbabve; fa=زیمباوه}
flag           : https://restcountries.eu/data/zwe.svg
regionalBlocs  : {@{acronym=AU; name=African Union; otherAcronyms=System.Object[]; otherNames=System.Object[]}}
cioc           : ZIM
###############################################################################################################################>

# ############################
$logFile = 'D:\03_PowerShell\PowerShell Scripts\ISO Country Code\ISOCountryCodes.log'
Start-Transcript -Path $logFile -Append

$isodate = Get-Date -Format ddMMMyyyy_HHhmmss

#BUILDING FILE PATH
$FilePath = "D:\03_PowerShell\PowerShell Scripts\ISO Country Code\"

#BUILDING JSON FILE PATH
$JsonFileName = "ISOCountryCode_$isodate"
$JsonFileExtn = ".json"
$JsonFileOutputPath = $FilePath+$JsonFileName+$JsonFileExtn

#BUILDING CSV FILE PATH
$CsvFileName = "ISOCountryCode_$isodate"
$CsvFileExtn = ".csv"

#CSV File Path
$CsvFileOutputPath = $FilePath+$CsvFileName+$CsvFileExtn

"The Log File is placed at: - $logFile"
"The ISO Date is: - $isodate "
"The Full File Path for the JSON File is: - $JsonFileOutputPath"
"The Full File Path for the CSV File is: - $CsvFileOutputPath"

#CLEAR RESULT SCREEN
cls

#INVOKE REST METHOD TO RETRIEVE DATA

$ISOCountryCode = Invoke-RestMethod "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"
$ISOCountryCodeFormatted = $ISOCountryCode | Select-Object @{Name="Country Name";Expression={$_."name"}} `
                                                          ,@{Name = "Internet Domain"; Expression={$_."topLevelDomain"}} `
                                                          ,@{Name = "Alpha 2 Code"; Expression={$_."alpha2Code"}} `
                                                          ,@{Name = "Alpha 3 Code"; Expression={$_."alpha3Code"}} `
                                                          ,@{Name = "Capital"; Expression={$_."capital"}} `
                                                          ,@{Name = "Continent"; Expression={$_."region"}} `
                                                          ,@{Name = "Area (LandMass)"; Expression={$_."area"}} `
                                                          ,@{Name = "Numeric Code"; Expression={$_."numericCode"}} `

<#BELOW COLUMNS AND VALUES TO BE USED AS REQUIRED
#,@{Name = "population"; Expression={$_."population"}} `
#,@{Name = "Languages Used"; Expression={$_."languages "}} `
#,@{Name = "International Dialing Code"; Expression={$_."callingCodes "}} `
#,@{Name = "Latitude/Longitude"; Expression={$_."latlng"}} `
#,@{Name = "Translations"; Expression={$_."translations"}} 
#,@{Name = "Country Direction/Location"; Expression={$_."subregion "}} `
#,@{Name = "Timezones"; Expression={$_."timezones "}} `
#,@{Name = "Borders"; Expression={$_."borders "}}#> `

#TEST THE CODE TO CONVERT RESULTSET TO JSON
#$JsonText = $Foo1 | ConvertTo-Json
#$JsonText

$ISOCountryCodeFormatted | ft

#BUILD A JSON FILE
$text | Set-Content $JsonFileOutputPath

#BUILD JSON FILE WITH HEADER > DATA > FOOTER
$JsonHeader = '{
  "ISOCountryCodes":' | Add-Content $JsonFileOutputPath
$ISOCountryCodeFormatted | ConvertTo-Json | Add-Content $JsonFileOutputPath
$JsonFooter = '}' | Add-Content $JsonFileOutputPath

#GENERATE CSV FILE
$ISOCountryCodeFormatted |Export-Csv $CsvFileOutputPath -encoding "unicode" -NoTypeInformation

#END TRANSCRIPT FOR LOGGING DATA FLOW
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say you could have just downloaded the HTMLAgilityPack, unzip it and place it on your Desktop. The is NO installation needed. That is the beauty of this pack. But good that you made your own script.